# PHP record not inserting to database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hi i'm a new PHP developer and its a language I'm just starting to pick up. I've tested my code and getting no errors but for some reason it won't add the values to the database.

- tested for syntax errors
- $mysqli is the name of the connection
- tested with string inputs, still wouldn't execute

As a php learner what other debugging steps should I take?

```
if($payment_status=='Completed'){

        $txn_id_check = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT `transaction_id` FROM `payment` WHERE `transaction_id`='$txn_id'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($txn_id_check)!=1){

                    // add txn_id to db
                    $query = "INSERT INTO `payment` (`transaction_id`, `payment_status`, `users_id`) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
                    $statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);
                    $statement->bind_param('ssi',$txn_id, $payment_status, $id);
                    if($statement->execute()){
                    print 'Success! ID of last inserted record is : ' .$statement->insert_id .'<br />'; 
                    }else{
                    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
                    }
                    $statement->close();



        }
```

Comment: is it executing inside if block?  if(mysqli_num_rows($txn_id_check)!=1) ???

Comment: add echo "inside if block" inside if, so that you can be sure if its really inside if block

Comment: Yeah it is executing inside the if statement

Comment: Do you see `'Success! ID of last inserted record is`?

Comment: No I don't see that message

Comment: And you don't see `Error : (` either?

Comment: How do your initialize `$mysqli` object?

Comment: `$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $user, $password, $dbname); //used to connect to the database` @u_mulder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose your problem is that you're mixing OO (object-oriented) and procedural ways of working with `mysqli`.

If your `$mysqli` variable is created via `new mysqli(/* params here */);` then you use OO approach and shouldn't use `mysqli_` prefixed functions.

In case `$mysqli` variable is `mysqli_connect(/* params here */);`
then you use procedural approach and you don't have `$mysqli` object to use `->` on it.

**Update.**

Ok, as you said - you create a `$mysqli` object via `new`.
Then, as I said `mysqli_` prefixed functions can't be used.
And you should change

```
$txn_id_check = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT `transaction_id` FROM `payment` WHERE `transaction_id`='$txn_id'");
```

to

```
$txn_id_check = $mysqli->query('Your query here');
// now $txn_id_check stores mysqli_result
```

And:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($txn_id_check)!=1) {
```

to

```
// use your mysqli_result to check number of rows
if($txn_id_check->num_rows != 1) {
```

Comment: This is how I connect to the db `$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $user, $password, $dbname); //used to connect to the database`

Comment: **Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in** From `$statement->bind_param('ssi',"hellooo", "Completed", 32);`

Comment: *Test inputs by the way*

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $txn_id is an integer and you are binding it as a string.  That will fail. What about $payment_status ? Is that a string? Remember that boolean type in mysql is seen as small INT too.

$statement->bind_param('ssi',$txn_id, $payment_status, $id);
Change it to: 'isi' or bind it to the appropriate type.

Also as @u_mulder pointed out, you are mixing procedural and object oriented style.

Comment: txn_id contains numbers and letters

Answer (score -1):

```
if($payment_status=='Completed'){

        $txn_id_check = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT 'transaction_id' FROM 'payment' WHERE 'transaction_id'='$txn_id'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($txn_id_check)!=1){

            //if($receiver_email=='fortunefilly@hotmail.com'){

                //if($payment_amount=='10.00' && $payment_currency=='GBP'){

                    // add txn_id to db
                    $query = "INSERT INTO 'payment' ('transaction_id', 'payment_status', 'users_id') VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
                    $statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);
                    $statement->bind_param('ssi',$txn_id, $payment_status, $id);
                    if($statement->execute()){
                    print 'Success! ID of last inserted record is : ' .$statement->insert_id .'<br />'; 
                    }else{
                    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
                    }
                    $statement->close();
                    // update premium to 1 

                    //$update_premium = mysqli_query("UPDATE 'users' SET is_member ='1' WHERE 'id' ='".$id."'");


        }
    }
```

This happened to me before, it was quite a hassle to detect the issue. The problem was with the single quotation marks instead of ` you must have '.

Comment: `SELECT 'transaction_id' FROM ` means select string `'transaction_id'`

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that... check your SQL syntax :)

Comment: Are there any more debugging steps I should take? Been stuck with this problem for quite some time

Comment: Did you try this code??? It has updated quotation marks .... literately it's the same piece of code with the right quotation marks

Comment: Are you connected to the database ? If you can post the snippet,, which shows how do you connect, it will be helpful to identify the problem

Comment: yeah include 'connect.php';